# JavaScript Global Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript

I had written a code as shown, where I was assigning a global variable a value, which suspended my further code execution.

resultCollection is the global variable. Also my program is running in strict mode.

```
"use strict";
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize : function(options){
         this.el = options.el;
         resultCollection = options.resultCollection;
         console.log('resultCollection',resultCollection);
         this.render();
     }
```

The console.log was never printed and the execution doesn't stop, just suspends or still executing when the global variable was assigned a value.

Why did this happen ? Can anyone give me some insight ?

Comment: Are you in a browser or in a server code ? Are you in a try/catch ?

Comment: it is client side javascript, hence on the browser. And it is not in a try/catch block. I am using BackboneJS wherein this code has been written in the initialize function of a certain Backbone View.

Comment: How about `window.resultCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

In the strict mode you should have seen the error in console.

So prepend your variable name with `window.` and it will work.

PS: see http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/6M3HM/

In console you would get `Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined`, whereas global `a` was defined well.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. When added to the Window object it will work. What I want to ask is why didn't the browser throw an exception inspite of using "strict mode".

Comment: @SrikanthManian: it does throw it. Check the jsfiddle link

Comment: I checked it, but why does it not throw in my particular code ?

Comment: @SrikanthManian: how would I guess what your code is? In my code it does, and it should always throw the error.

Comment: @SrikanthManian: I see now :-S That's strange

Comment: strict mode is only activated if "use strict" is first token in a script file or function body. In your code is this the case? Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: Yes, it is on the first line of the file.